# For loop equivalent in Facelets

Tags: jsf, facelets

How can I do something similar the below in Facelets?

```
for(int i=0; i<=80; i++){
<f:selectItem  itemLabel=i itemValue=i />
}
```

I have combined both Java and Facelets code in my above code, but I want something like this to work in Facelets. I need the `itemLabel` and `itemValue` to be incremented, when the page is loaded. I need to display all values from 1 to 80 as dropdown options.

Is it possible to do so, or is there any other method to achieve the same?

Comment: instead of the usual for you can use the jsf syntax <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="10"></c:forEach> but other than that I don't think there is any loop in html as a language

Comment: If you want to iterate over a collection you can use a4j:repeat (http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Tables_and_grids.html#sect-Component_Reference-Actions-a4jrepeat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.someList}" var="someVal"
     itemLabel="#{someVal.someLabel}" itemValue="#{someVal.someVal}" />
```

Where `someList` is a List of Objects...

Also , you should take a look at [OmniFaces Showcase - Arrays](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Arrays)  , There are several examples you might find relevant

otherwise you can do it with `c:forEach` with `<f:selectItem` as proposed by @AurA

Comment: thank you Daniel as u suggested i created a list in my bean level and called that object in xhtml page and itseems working fine...............:) thank you once again....

Answer (score -2):

I think this may be what you are looking for?

```
<select>
for(int i=0; i<=80; i++){
   <option value = i>i</option>
}
</select>
```

Not 100% of what you are trying to achieve - I'm assuming this is a `for` loop in php (or you can use JS) and that your just trying to create a simple (x/html) select form within a loop? html/xhtml does not have a loop function, it is for pure markup only. If I'm misunderstanding you then please clarify your question and I will try to help you better.